# Docker images vs Helm Charts

Tags: docker, kubernetes, helm

First of all I apologies because I am developer trying to understand some server stuffs. I request the moderators please don't be harsh if this question doesn't make any sense here.

From my understanding we have docker images inside docker hub which we use to run containers. So for me docker hub images are packages of images. To manage containers we use kubernates. Now helm is the pacakage manager for kubernates. Helm charts are packages for docker-images or kubernate clusers or what?

Comment: here's an analogy: if 1 docker container is 1 thread, then kube/helm is many, often a dynamic number of threads. someone correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 6):

First focus on the important stuff: docker and for smaller projects docker-compose.

Kubernetes, Helm, .. are tools to orchestrate large scale deployments and are in many cases overblown solutions.
All of them are  (currently) based on docker. If you understand docker well, then getting an understanding of kubernetes and helm will be easier. Basically helm can be used to "render" kubernetes specifications.

Comment: Can you distinguish helm chars and docker images?